# React : How to set initial values on select component of antd library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

When using the parameter **defaultValue** of the component Select no values is found.

```
<Select
     mode='multiple'
     allowClear
     style={{ width: '100%' }}
     placeholder='Sélectionner...'
     onChange={setValue}
     onSelect={handleSelect}
     defaultValue={dataChecked}
     onDeselect={handleDeselect}
>
    { 
        dataType.map((v) => (
            <Option key={v.valueKey} value={v.valueKey}>
                 <img className='img-step' src={`http://localhost:2023/api/pictures/${props.typeUrlPicture}/${v.picture}`} alt={v.picture}/>
                  {" "}{v.label}
            </Option>
         ))
    }
</Select>
```

Here I use **dataChecked** as a variable. **dataChecked** is a array of value.

```
     const [ data, setData ] = useState([])
     const dataType = data.map((l)=> ({ label: l.name, value: l.picture, valueKey: l.id, picture: l.picture }))
     const [ value, setValue ] = useState([])

     const [ dataChecked, setDataChecked ] = useState([])

     useEffect(() => {

          fetch(`${baseUrl}/properties?type=${props.type}`)
               .then((res) => res.json())
               .then((data) => {
                    setData(data)
               })

          fetch(`${baseUrl}/steps/${props.idBdd}`)
               .then((res) => res.json())
               .then((data) => {
                    data.properties.filter(d => d.type === props.type).map((d) => (
                         setDataChecked(current => [...current, d.id])
                    ))              
               })


          return () => {
               setData([])
               setDataChecked([])
          }
                    
     }, [props.type, props.idBdd])
```

The values ​​of my **Options** are indeed integers like the values ​​of my **dataChecked** array.
If I replace **dataChecked** with an array : [1,9]. I get my initial values. And
when I **console.log(dataChecked)** I get an array of [1,9] for example but my component gets no initial value.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example using codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, you can try.

```html
<!-- 1. Use value prop -->
<Select mode="multiple" value={defaultValue}></Select>

<!-- 2. Set defaultValue to key -->
<Select mode="multiple" key={defaultValue.join(',')}></Select>
```